# PineScript problem, shifting current series into the past

Tags: pine-script

I want to shift "close" series into the past by X elements and then populate those X elements with data to simulate how %B, RSI, ema/sma, etc is affected in the future.

hist[5] = close

hist[4] = 5

hist[3] = 5.5

hist[2] = 5

hist[1] = 4.5

hist[0] = 6

I want to compute ema/sma/rsi etc on series "hist". How can I do this with PineScript?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible. I can not get the `close` of the last bar 6 bars early. ***You can not peek into the future***. But if you only want to know some values of these indicators, just fill in the `close` by hand and let it plot the result. This will show up in the beginning of the chart.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=false)

data = array.new<float>()
array.push(data, 100)
array.push(data, 5)
array.push(data, 5.5)
array.push(data, 4.5)
array.push(data, 6)

current = array.get(data, bar_index < array.size(data) ? bar_index : 4)
plot(ta.ema(current, 5))
```

But if you really want this. Then **you need to implement the TA functions your selfs** one by one and hardcode the values as you already did.

*Example of EMA*

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=false)

m(weight, price) => price * weight
ema(close) => (m(1, close) + m(2, 5) + m(3, 5.5) + m(4, 4.5) + m(5, 6)) / 15

plot(ema(close))
```

SMA is the same but then a 1 for all weights and then divide by 5 and not 15. The others are also not to hard but more work. Hope i awnsered your question. Or at least give you something to work with.

Extra tip: Some TA functions do need the data in a specified order like `ta.sma` but `ta.ema` does. Thus maybe you can take a shortcut.

For questions about implementing your own TA functions, just ask here at stackoverflow.

Comment: I want to compute TA across past, current, and simulated future data with continuity. I am not "peaking at the future" ... Thank for the idea of the arrays, I will see if that makes things easier or not as v5 has many new features.

Answer (score 0):

While you can refer to past values of series, you cannot modify them. Only the current series value can be assigned a value.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator